# snmpd configuration + how to set snmpd correctly

Tags: linux, rhel, snmp

Regarding the following snmpd.conf file:

```
more /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

rocommunity bingo 127.0.0.1
rocommunity bingo server18
rocommunity bingo  server19
syscontact server3
syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity bingo

trapsink  server18 bingo
```

Is the line with trapsink necessary, since we defined these lines ?

```
rocommunity bingo server18
rocommunity bingo  server19
```

Second, what is the target of the line with syscontact?